# If $τ_x^k$ is the time of the $k$-th entrance of a Markov chain into $x$, then $\text P_x[τ_y^k<∞]=\text P_x[τ_y^1<∞](\text P_y[τ_y^1<∞])^{k-1}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be at most countable and equipped with the discrete topology and $\mathcal E$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a discrete Markov chain with values in $(E,\mathcal E$) and distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$
- $\tau_x^0:=0$ and $$\tau_x^k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau_x^{k-1}:X_n=x\right\}$$ for $x\in E$ and $k\in\mathbb N$

Let $$\varrho(x,y):=\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^1<\infty\right]\color{blue}{=\operatorname P_x\left[\exists n\in\mathbb N:X_n=y\right]}\;.$$
I want to prove, that $$\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\right]=\varrho(x,y)\varrho(y,y)^{k-1}\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N\tag 1$$ using the strong Markov property: $$\operatorname E_x\left[f\circ (X_{\tau+t})_{t\in \mathbb N_0}\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]=\operatorname E_{X_\tau}\left[f\circ X\right]\tag 2$$ for all $x\in E$, $\sigma(X)$-stopping times $\tau$ and bounded, $\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N_0}$-measurable $f:E^{\mathbb N_0}\to\mathbb R$.

---

I want to prove $(1)$ by induction over $k\in\mathbb N$. Since, $k=1$ is trivial, we only need to care about $k-1\to k$. Since $$\left\{\tau_y^{k-1}<\infty\right\}\cap\left\{\tau_y^k<\infty\right\}=\left\{\tau_y^k<\infty\right\}$$ and $$\left\{\tau_y^{k-1}<\infty\right\}\in\mathcal F_{\tau_y^{k-1}}\;,$$ we've got $$\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\right]=\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau_y^{k-1}<\infty\right\}}\color{red}{\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\mid\mathcal F_{\tau_y^{k-1}}\right]}\right]\;,\tag 4$$ by definition of the conditional expectation. Now, I think, that we somehow need to apply $(2)$ with $\tau=\tau_y^{k-1}$ to the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term in order to obtain $$\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau_y^{k-1}<\infty\right\}}\color{red}{\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\mid\mathcal F_{\tau_y^{k-1}}\right]}\right]=\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau_y^{k-1}<\infty\right\}}\varrho(y,y)\right]\;,$$ but I can't figure out how I need to choose $f$.

Comment: I must say I am not really familiar with this area, but it looks like the following 2 facts are being applied:
1) strong Markov property and 
2) identity function $1_{\left \{ ... \right \}}$

Comment: @rtybase I didn't thought that the strong Markov property was applied in this first step. What do you think for which $f$ it was used?

Comment: See point 2) ... i.e. $f\equiv 1_{\left \{  \right \}}$

Comment: After EDIT 2, close the question? Or still unclear?

Comment: @Did Yes, at least if you agree, that my argumentation is correct. Do you?

Comment: Yup. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Unfortunately, after this easy step, I still don't know how the strong Markov property comes into play. How do I need to choose $f$?

Comment: $$f\circ (X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb N_0}=1_{\left\{\tau_y^{1}<\infty\right\}}$$

Comment: @Did Are you sure? I had thought that $$f\circ X=1_{\left\{\tau_y^{\color{red}k}<\infty\right\}}\;.\tag 3$$ However, I still don't get how I need to choose $f$ such that $(3)$ holds.

Comment: Yes I am sure... Actually, either you apply "my" $f$ at time $\tau^{k-1}_y$, or you apply "your" $f$ at time $\tau^{1}_y$.

Comment: Sorry but this cannot go on forever... "Can you provide an answer?" **I did**.

Comment: No mistake, as I said there are two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the strong Markov property $(2)$ at time $\tau:=\tau_y^{k-1}$, we need to find a bounded, $\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N_0}$-measurable function $f:E^{\mathbb N_0}\to\mathbb R$ with $$f\circ\tilde X=1_{\left\{\tau^+<\infty\right\}}\;,$$ where $\tilde X:=\left(X_{\tau+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $\tau^+:=\tau_y^k$. Since

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\{\tau^+<\infty\right\}&=&\left\{\exists n>\tau:X_n=y\right\}\\
&=&\left\{\exists n\in\mathbb N:\tilde X_n=y\right\}\\
&=&\left\{\exists n\in\mathbb N:\pi_n\circ\tilde X=y\right\}\;,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\pi_n:E^{\mathbb N_0}\to E$ denotes the $n$-th coordinate map, we can choose $f$ to be the indicator function of $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\pi_n=y\right\}\;.$$

Noting that $f\circ X$ is the indicator function of $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{X_n=y\right\}=\left\{\tau_y^1<\infty\right\}$$ and $X_\tau=y$ on $\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}$, we're now able to conclude, that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\operatorname E_x\left[f\circ\tilde X\mid\mathcal F_{\tau}\right]\right]&\stackrel{(2)}=&\;\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\operatorname E_{X_\tau}\left[f\circ X\right]\right]\\
&=&\;\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\operatorname P_{X_\tau}\left[\tau_y^1<\infty\right]\right]\\
&=&\;\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\operatorname P_y\left[\tau_y^1<\infty\right]\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{def}}=&\;\operatorname E_x\left[1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\varrho(y,y)\right]\\
&=&\;\varrho(y,y)\operatorname P_x\left[\tau<\infty\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{IH}}=&\;\varrho(y,y)\varrho(x,y)\varrho(y,y)^{k-2}\;.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: You guy made me feel dumb about maths.